# Matlab error: Cannot program Arduino board Uno. Please make sure the board is supported and the port and board type are correct

Tags: matlab, arduino

I want to control a Arduino Uno with Matlab. But when trying to activate the Arduino with in the Matlab Console ( a=arduino('Com7','uno')) I first get a message:

> Updating server code on Arduino Uno (COM7). Please wait.

and then get the error message:

> Cannot program Arduino board Uno (COM7). Please make sure the board is supported and the port and board type are correct.

Does anyone had the same problem and solved it? Or does anyone has an idea what the exact problem is?

Matlab Version: 2014b (64bit) with the Arduino Support Package installed over the supportPackageInstaller

Arduino Software Version: 1.6.5 (The Arduino Support Package from Matlab comes with an older Arduino Software 1.5.6 - and tried also the 1.0.5 version but error still occures)

Windows 7 prof.

I tried [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/31595-connecting-to-arduino-timeout)
and [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/161002-cannot-connect-arduino-uno-to-matlab-r2014b),
but there was no solution. I searched the web for the last 6 hours - with no pay off...so now I turn to you guys. 
I hope you can help. Would be very grateful!
Thanks a lot
Marc

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions to the problem:

1.Run MATLAB as an admin in windows

2.Remove winavr if installed in the computer(alternatively you may remove the winavr related directory paths from PATH environment variable)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Arduino Mega2560 clone and I solved the problem running Matlab as Administrator. Installing the Matlab legacy package for arduino also worked.